# 32bit IEDriverServer.exe is instantiating 64bit IE in Windows 10 (Java Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver

I can't find anyone else running into this issue so I keep feeling like I must be missing something here.  Our framework has been working fine on Win7 and we are now trying to test our scripts to make sure they work in Windows 10 as well.

We are using the 32bit IEDriverServer.exe, but in Windows 10, it's starting up the 64bit version of IE instead of the 32bit version.  If you read the documentation on IEDriverServer.exe, it says the 32bit version will open 32bit version of IE, and vice versa for the 64bit IEDriverserver.exe.

Does anyone know why on Windows 10, we are seeing the 64bit version of IE opening? (Not edge but IE11 on Windows 10).

Comment: Which selenium and IE driver versions are you using?

Comment: Using Selenium 2.53.0 and IEDriverServer 2.53.1

Comment: Just curious - How did you verify that it's the 64bit version of IE? According to this link https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/32-or-64-bit-version-of-internet-explorer/d8fb9b92-778b-4475-8f33-8f3791423259, unless EPM is turned on, IE is running as 32bit.

Comment: In task manager, I right cliked the instance running and looked at properties.  The file location shows C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer as opposed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer when I open the 32bit version.  
I only noticed though because I was running an AutoIt script (Which handles the certificate selection dialog box that Selenium can't handle) and was working fine until I incorportated it into our Selenium Scirpt.  That's when I dug some more and noticed this AuotIt script doesn't work against 64bit IE but works fine with the 32bit IE.

Comment: Thanks for the link AngieM.  I used the tool but still that doesn't really give a clear answer on 64bit vs 32bit.  No matter which I open, there will be a parent iexplore.exe and child iexplore.exe, regardless of whether I open 32bit of 64bit, the parent will show 64bit, while child shows 32bit.